# Creating a Table with Varying Columns

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

I'm trying to create a table that looks like :

[image]

but have no idea how to fiddle with the number of varying columns. e.g. "Term Plan" row has 1 column, week 17 has 2 columns, other rows have 3 columns. Would also prefer if the table is page-breakable like this tcolorbox table :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{colframe=gray,fonttitle=\bfseries,adjusted
title=\centering#1,breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Stuff}
\lipsum
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Which upon compiling shows :

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with `ltablex` which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. Note  that such tables can break across pages, but only between rows, not inside a multiline row:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{ltablex, ragged2e, bigstrut, multirow, makecell}
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{10pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\begin{document}

{\keepXColumns\sffamily
\setlist{wide=0pt, leftmargin=*}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|*{2}{>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}X|}}
    \hline
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender} \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\bfseries TERM PLAN\bigstrut} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}\bfseries WEEK & \centering\bfseries LEARNING OUTCOMES & \centering\bfseries TOPICS {\&} SKILLS \bigstrut\tabularnewline
\hline
\endfirsthead
  \multirow{5}{*}{15}
  & \begin{itemize}[nosep, before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
\item find the maximum or minimum value of a quadratic function
\item use the maximum or minimum value of a function to sketch the graph or determine the range for a given domain
\end{itemize}
 & \textbf{Quadratic Functions}
\begin{enumerate}[label=4.\arabic*, noitemsep, after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip-3pt}]
\item Maximum/Minimum value of a qua\-dratic expression
\item Roots of a quadratic equation
\item Solving quadratic inequalities
\end{enumerate} \\
\hline
17 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Revision for Continuous Assessment 3\\
 Continuous Assessment 3}\bigstrut} \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Suppose I'd like to center the number '15' in the first column (push it down towards the center of the row), how do I go about doing that? I've tried \begin{center} \end{center}, \centerline{} and \[ \] but they don't seem to work.

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo: You can use `\multicolumn` and `\makecell` for the new row, and `\multirow` for the vertical centring of numbers in the left column. Note the first argument of `\multirow` is not the number of rows, but the number of lines (more or less). Please see my updated code and screenshot.

Comment: What does the second argument for \multirow do? The one you marked with an asterisk.

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo: The second mandatory argument of `\multirow` sets the width of the multirow cell.`*` means it has the natural width of its  content. In a column with fixed width (`p` type), you also can use`=` to stipulate  it will have the column width. All this is explained in § 3 of the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Tables like this can be created using multirow and multicolumn. See the [multirow documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow).

This is a MWE for your table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{cll}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{F}\\
\hline
Week & Learning Outcomes & Topics \& Skills\\
\hline
15 & Text... & Text... \\
\hline
16 & Text... & Text... \\
\hline
17 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{This is demo text}\\
\hline
18 & \multirow{2}{*}{This is demo text} & Hi\\
19 &  & Hi\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This is the minimum and not actually pretty. It produces the following:
[image: Table from MWE]

### A bit prettier

Something prettier would look like this (using the booktabs package):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 

\begin{longtable}{cll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{F}\\
\midrule
Week & Learning Outcomes & Topics \& Skills\\
\hline
15 & Text... & Text... \\
\hline
16 & Text... & Text... \\
\hline
17 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{This is demo text}\\
\hline
18 & \multirow{2}{*}{This is demo text} & Hi\\
19 &  & Hi\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Improved table]

Comment: How do you include vertical lines to separate the columns in this case?

Comment: Change `\begin{longtable}{cll}` to  `\begin{longtable}{c|l|l}`. 
The vertical bars indicate the vertical bars that separate the columns of the table.

Comment: I ended up with something like this instead : https://puu.sh/B1Fe3/9e5839c8c9.png . Also I'm getting a Badbox error, Underfull \vbox (badness 1000).